# Окрашивание при наведении и нажатии, расположение на одной строчке

Tags: html, jquery

Помогите осуществить следующее. Нужно чтобы Лично и Представитель были на одной строчке, при наведении на них - окрашивались и когда на них нажмешь то показывали другой цвет.

```js
$(".tab_item").not(":first").hide();
$(".wrapper .tab").click(function() {
  $(".wrapper .tab").removeClass("active").eq($(this).index()).addClass("active");
  $(".tab_item").hide().eq($(this).index()).fadeIn()
}).eq(0).addClass("active");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tabs">
    <span class="tab"><h2>Лично</h2></span>
    <span class="tab"><h2>Представитель</h2></span>
  </div>
  <div class="tab_content">
    <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 1</div>
    <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: добавьте css пожалуйста. _Нужно чтобы Лично и Представитель были на одной строчке..._*:* пожалуйста, продемонстрируйте начальное состояние.

Comment: css я не использовал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".tab_item").not(":first").hide();
$(".wrapper .tab").click(function() {
  $(".wrapper .tab").removeClass("active").eq($(this).index()).addClass("active");
  $(".tab_item").hide().eq($(this).index()).fadeIn()
}).eq(0).addClass("active");
```

```css
.tabs h2 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline;
}

.tabs h2:hover {
  background:lightgreen;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.tab.active h2 {
  background:lightpink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tabs">
    <span class="tab"><h2>Лично</h2></span>
    <span class="tab"><h2>Представитель</h2></span>
  </div>
  <div class="tab_content">
    <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 1</div>
    <div class="tab_item">Содержимое 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Можно добавить типа руки когда наводишь на Лично или Представитель, 
и чтобы при нажатии оставался нажатый цвет

Comment: @dmr не понял при нажатый цвет. Разве сейчас не так?

Comment: При нажатии цвет меняет но не остается

Comment: @dmr Вы пробуете последнюю версию ответа? У меня - остается, Chrome и Edge.

Comment: Все понял, большое спасибо